# How to keep appended elements inside parent-element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please re-size the width of output and take a look at this demo:

```css
cite{
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  border:2px solid;
}

span{
  padding: 0px 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<cite>
  <span>one</span>
  <span>two</span>
  <span>tjree</span>
  <span>four</span>
</cite>
```

All fine. Now when I append those `<span>` elements using JS, then boundary of `<cite>` fails. take a look at this:

```js
$("cite").html("<span>one</span><span>two</span><span>tjree</span><span>four</span>");
```

```css
cite{
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  border:2px solid;
}

span{
  padding: 0px 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<cite></cite>
```

AS I said, I want always keep those `<span>` inside of `<cite>` *(to change `height` of `cite` when there is overflow)*. How can I do that?

---

**Note:** These two property are vital and I cannot remove/change them:

```
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display: inline-block` to `span` [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/78/)

```js
$("cite").html("<span>one</span><span>two</span><span>tjree</span><span>four</span>");
```

```css
cite{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  border: 2px solid;
}

span{
  padding: 0px 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<cite></cite>
```